# eos_vlan and ansible, "cli command "vlan 777" failed: invalid command"

Tags: python, ansible, eos

I am a newbie at Ansible and Networking, however I have started a job at networking company, where we have started using Ansible for automatizing configurations for network nodes. Juniper devices show no problem, however Arista switches pose issues when trying to relay simple commands.

So what I am trying to achieve is to create vlans at Arista switches using Ansible. 
I am using eapi connection using https (sensitive data replaced with xxx):

```
show management api http-commands
Enabled:        Yes
HTTPS server:   running, set to use port 443
HTTP server:    shutdown, set to use port 80
VRF:            MGMT
Hits:           318
Last hit:       766 seconds ago
Bytes in:       25241
Bytes out:      3985523
Requests:       40
Commands:       80
Duration:       79.082 seconds
   User       Hits       Bytes in       Bytes out    Last hit        
---------- ---------- -------------- --------------- --------------- 
   xxx       40         25241          3985523      766 seconds ago 

URLs                                  
------------------------------------- 
Vlan2       : https://xxx
```

here is my task:

```
     - name: create vlan
       eos_vlan:
          vlan_id: "{{ vlan_id }}"
          name: "{{ vlan_descr }}"
          state: present
          authorize: yes
          auth_pass: "{{ auth_password }}"
          transport: "{{ transport }}"
          username: "{{ username }}"
          password: "{{ password }}"
          validate_certs: false
          ssh_keyfile: "{{ ssh_keyfile }}"
```

as you can see I use authorize password, all variables are stored in another file. The problem is that I receive this error:

`changed": false, "code": 1002, "msg": "CLI command 2 of 2 'vlan 777' failed: invalid command"`

This server runs on:

```
     CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
     Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-957.21.2.el7.x86_64
     Architecture: x86-64
```

Using Ansible:

```
  config file = /opt/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, May  2 2019, 20:40:44) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)]
```

Arista version:

```
Arista DCS-7050QX-32-F
Hardware version:    02.00
Software image version: 4.13.5F
Architecture:           i386
```

I have tried this on test environment using same tasks, however different ansible VM and arista image:

```
Arista vEOS
Hardware version:    
Serial number:       
Software image version: 4.21.1.1F
Architecture:           i386
Internal build version: 4.21.1.1F-10146868.42111F
```

and all seemed ok, used same documentations for setting up users and so on.

I believe it may be due to user not having privileges, but I include admin password and both eapi and ansible users have network-admin roles.

Here is more detailed output:

```
fatal: [x.x.x.x]: FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "code": 1002,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "aggregate": null,
            "associated_interfaces": null,
            "auth_pass": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "authorize": true,
            "delay": 10,
            "host": "x.x.x.x",
            "interfaces": null,
            "name": null,
            "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "port": 443,
            "provider": {
                "auth_pass": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                "authorize": true,
                "host": "x.x.x.x",
                "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                "port": 443,
                "ssh_keyfile": "/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub",
                "timeout": 45,
                "transport": "eapi",
                "use_proxy": true,
                "use_ssl": true,
                "username": "eapi",
                "validate_certs": false
            },
            "purge": false,
            "ssh_keyfile": "/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub",
            "state": "present",
            "timeout": 45,
            "transport": "eapi",
            "url_password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "url_username": "eapi",
            "use_ssl": true,
            "username": "eapi",
            "validate_certs": false,
            "vlan_id": 777
        }
    },
    "msg": "CLI command 2 of 2 'vlan 777' failed: invalid command"
}
```

Another thing worth noticing is that if I use the vlan that already exists, and do not include description (so that no changes are made), Ansible returns success:

```
ok: [x.x.x.x] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "commands": [],
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "aggregate": null,
            "associated_interfaces": null,
            "auth_pass": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "authorize": true,
            "delay": 10,
            "host": "x.x.x.x",
            "interfaces": null,
            "name": null,
            "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "port": 443,
            "provider": {
                "auth_pass": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                "authorize": true,
                "host": "x.x.x.x",
                "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                "port": 443,
                "ssh_keyfile": "/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub",
                "timeout": 45,
                "transport": "eapi",
                "use_proxy": true,
                "use_ssl": true,
                "username": "eapi",
                "validate_certs": false
            },
            "purge": false,
            "ssh_keyfile": "/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub",
            "state": "present",
            "timeout": 45,
            "transport": "eapi",
            "url_password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "url_username": "eapi",
            "use_ssl": true,
            "username": "eapi",
            "validate_certs": false,
            "vlan_id": 777
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone point me towards the place where I should look for answers? 
Or any suggestions at all? I would extremely appreciate that.

Thanks

Comment: I can confirm that I can log in to the switches using eapi and ansible users and create vlans without problems, but using eos_vlan or eos_config and putting in the same lines, I get the error mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in my question all along:
turns out it was due to software version:

```
   Arista DCS-7050QX-32-F 
   Hardware version: 02.00 
   Software image version: 4.13.5F 
   Architecture: i386
```

You need at least `4.15.5F` tu run with `Ansible 2.8.1`